# jQuery error in IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

This isn't working in IE9.

Works great in IE 7/8 and every other browser. It basically ignores the hide/show and treats the links like anchor tags (which should be overwritten with the preventDefault)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".tabContents").hide(); // Hide all tab conten divs by default
    $(".tabContents:first").show(); // Show the first div of tab content by default
    $("#tabContaier ul li a.tablink").click(function (e) { //Fire the click event
        e.preventDefault();
        var activeTab = $(this).attr("href"); // Catch the click link
        $("#tabContaier ul li a.tablink").removeClass("active"); // Remove pre-highlighted link
        $(this).addClass("active"); // set clicked link to highlight state
        $(".tabContents").hide(); // hide currently visible tab content div
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); // show the target tab content div by matching clicked link.
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gpnqV/

Comment: What do you mean it isn't working?  Is it supposed to "Collection Details" when you click the "Collection Details" link?  That's what your Fiddle is doing for me in IE9.

Comment: may be some issue with plugins installed on your IE9. Try disabling all plugins.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Must be a conflict somewhere.